# Gremlin query to retrieve nodes of OrientDB Generic classes

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

Having one class UserRoles which is not extending to any superclass V. How I will get the vertices for this.

The following query doesn't work:

```
g.traversal().V().hasLabel("UserRoles").toList()
```

Comment: which version of orientdb and gremlin? which client?

Comment: Gremlin version-3.3.3, Orient DB version-3.0.4